# Python project setup in visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a python project setup in visual studio code. Below is how a part of code looks like

```
...
from .pgcompleter import PGCompleter
from .pgtoolbar import create_toolbar_tokens_func
from .pgstyle import style_factory
from .pgexecute import PGExecute
from .pgbuffer import PGBuffer
from .completion_refresher import CompletionRefresher
from .config import (get_casing_file,
    load_config, config_location, ensure_dir_exists, get_config)
from .key_bindings import pgcli_bindings
from .encodingutils import utf8tounicode
from .encodingutils import text_type
...
```

files such as `pgcompleter` etc. are from my project only.

And, here is my launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "env": {},
            "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
            "debugOptions": [
                "RedirectOutput"
            ]
        }
}
```

When I try to debug I get an error on the console

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<absolute_path_to>main.py", line 43, in <module>
    from .pgcompleter import PGCompleter
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

Okay, so I know two workarounds

-- `python -m some_folder_name.main.py`

-- and, changing the imports like

```
from pgcompleter import PGCompleter
from pgtoolbar import create_toolbar_tokens_func
from pgstyle import style_factory
```

I just want to know that is it possible to make it work without changing the imports?

Answer (score 0):

To create an entry point for a package you use a file called `__main__.py`. So change your `main.py` to `__main__.py` then run `python -m some_folder_name`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an `__init__.py` file in the same directory as files such as `pgcompleter.py`. This converts it from a regular directory to a Python package.

Comment: Does it work if you try to run it like a module?

`python -m some_folder_name` with a file named `__main__.py`